# Python test and mock for imported module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pytest

I have a module that imports another module like this:

```
#main-file.py
import src.FetchFunction.video_service.fields.urls as urls

def some_func():
  return urls.fetch()
```

now I want to test this file like this:

```
import unittest
import src.FetchFunction.video_service.fields.urls as urls
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class MainFileTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_example(self):
      urls.fetch = MagicMock(return_value='mocked_resp')
      assertSomething()
```

this part works well and does what I want.
BUT
this affects other tests file...
I mean I have other tests that use the "urls.fetch"
and now instead of getting the proper flow
they get the above mocked response.

Any idea?

- quite sure its not related but Im using `pytest` to run my tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) in a context to define the scope where the mocked `fetch` should be used. In the example below, outside the `with` block the `urls.fetch` is reverted to the original value:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class MainFileTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_example(self):
        with patch('urls.fetch', return_value='mocked_resp'):
            # urls.fetch is mocked now
            assertSomething()
        # urls.fetch is not mocked anymore
```

Comment: where were you 4 days ago... Thanks!

Comment: sorry ^_^ but glad to hear it helped you!

Comment: Hey @hoefling any ideas on how to mock this imported module in the tested file. "from .modifiers import Modifiers". Patch does seem to be nice

Comment: Do you want to mock the module? Or do you want to mock what you actually import from it (`Modifiers` class)? Check out [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48847105/2650249) for the mocking possibilities for the imported stuff.